# in Android, return from audioplayer started with action_view

Tags: android

I put a audio button on the google map and after I press the button, the audio player is started to play the sound file, however, when the sound is complete and return back to my google map fragment, all the markers are lost and the google map is just shows at the very large scale (oceans and continents).
Anyone knows how to return to the original google map after sound play is done?
Thanks.
code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();  
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
    File file = new File(YOUR_SONG_URI);  
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");  
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It could be because of your google map related value is reset. Not because you call the audio player. Show your related google maps code.

Comment: you are right, I reset the fragment in the onResume function.